# Rotating an img that has absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a circle div that has images along the outside of the div. Using javascript, I rotate it a quarter every 4 seconds. In order to keep the images from tilting, I am rotating them the opposite direction. This works in keeping them from tilting, but it causes them to move form being on the perimeter of the circle. I think this is because the position is absolute. Any advice?

```js
amount=0;
ids=['box1','box2','box3']

setInterval(rotate, 4000);
///clearTimeout(time);

function rotate() {

  document.getElementById("graphicContainer").setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + amount * 2 * Math.PI / (ids.length).toString() + "rad)");

  document.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + -amount * 2 * Math.PI / (ids.length).toString() + "rad)");
  document.getElementById("box2").setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + -amount * 2 * Math.PI / (ids.length).toString() + "rad)");
  document.getElementById("box3").setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + -amount * 2 * Math.PI / (ids.length).toString() + "rad)");

  amount = amount + 1;

}
```

```css
#graphicContainer div img {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#graphicContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
  transform-origin: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

#box1,
#box2,
#box3 {
  transform-origin: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="graphicContainer">

  <div class="box" id="box1"> <img id="goalsGraphic" src="../images/running.jpg"> </div>

  <div class="box" id="box2"> <img id="workGraphic" src="../images/work.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3"> <img id="progressGraphic" src="../images/progress.jpg"> </div>

</div>
```

There should be two other small images on the circle, but they are moving in their own circles instead below the screenshot view.
[image]

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted the css styles
img container should have:

- `position:absolute`, so they can move and position freely to match the circle.
- `top: 50%; left: 50%` so its transformation center point is the circle's center

img should have `margin-top: -25%; margin-left: -50%` or any other style that allows displacement by that much, to account for image height and width.

Using `translate` transform to offset 50% positioning

```js
amount=0;
ids=['box1','box2','box3']

setInterval(rotate, 4000);
///clearTimeout(time);

const cssrotfn = a=>`transform: rotate(${a}deg) translate(250px) rotate(${-a}deg)`
const cssrotbyidx = (idx, len)=>cssrotfn(idx * 360/len)
rotate()

function rotate() {
//  document.getElementById("graphicContainer").setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + amount * 2 * Math.PI / (ids.length).toString() + "rad)");

  document.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("style", cssrotbyidx(1+amount,3));
  document.getElementById("box2").setAttribute("style", cssrotbyidx(2+amount,3));
  document.getElementById("box3").setAttribute("style", cssrotbyidx(3+amount,3));

  amount = amount + 1;

}
```

```css
#graphicContainer div img {
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
  transform-origin: center;
  
  margin-top: -25%; margin-left: -50%;
}

#graphicContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
  transform-origin: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

#box1,
#box2,
#box3 {
  transform-origin: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="graphicContainer">

  <div class="box" id="box1"> <img id="goalsGraphic" src="https://i.imgur.com/CW9CiQ6.jpg"> </div>

  <div class="box" id="box2"> <img id="workGraphic" src="https://i.imgur.com/CW9CiQ6.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3"> <img id="progressGraphic" src="https://i.imgur.com/CW9CiQ6.jpg"> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove *transform-origin: center;* and change position to *absolute* and shift images on circle it work fine

```
#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    /* transform-origin: center; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 80px;
    transition: all 1.75s ease-in;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```